# Track changes to outlook settings

Tags: outlook

I'm currently wondering if there is a way to track what changes where made and when they where made to the settings of a particular users Microsoft outlook account? It seems it would be an excellent feature for settling some security disputes but I am unsure how often the problem would arise however I could certainly do with it right now. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. I bielive all profile settings are stored in the windows registry. You can try using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for viewing changes on the fly.